# How can I change the template CodeRush uses when it extracts a method?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, coderush

When I extract a method in CodeRush, it has some default formatting.  I'd like to change it.  Specifically, when I choose the location of the extracted method, CodeRush smashes it in, directly above the method I put the location marker at.

So:

When I choose to drop the extracted method, like this:
[image: Extract Method Location]

It ends up looking like this:
[image: Extract Method Results]

What I want is for it to have some control over how the method looks, at the moment I want to add some blank lines between it and the next method.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the DevExpress -> Options dialog;

Go to the Editor | Code Formatting | Blank Lines option page;

Toggle the 'After multi-line members' option.

Comment: Turns out that my initial problem was that I had the Options dialog set to the Beginner Level.  Once I changed it to Advanced I was able to see the Code Formatting option.

Answer (score 2):

I requested this here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S130722.aspx

It got implemented here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S19229.aspx

There's now a massive formatting subsystem I spent 3 hours fighting that tries to outdo ReSharper's massive formatting subsystem which both need to be able to survive VS Autoformat (CtrlK D) and don't always.

Now you know it's there, I'd appreciate a quick summary from you as to whether you were able to make it do what you wanted!

Comment: Is there a way to override specific options in the Code Formatting dialog?  I see the blank line option, but I'd like to get multiple blank lines in some cases.  This should probably be a new question...

Comment: There is no such capability at the moment.